# How to input numbers using auto loop in c++

Tags: c++, vector, auto

How to input numbers using auto loop in c++

For example I Have a products of burgers , fried and soda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main(){
    
    
    std::vector<std::string> products = {"burgers","fries","sodas"};
    std::vector<int> numbers = {};
    int a;
     for (auto n : products)
        std::cout <<"Enter number of "<< n << ": \n";
        std::cin >>a;
        numbers.push_back(a);

    return 0;
}
```

After i run this code this is the output

```
Enter number of burgers:
Enter number of fries:
Enter number of sodas:
1 // this is the only input
```

I want the output just like this

```
   Enter number of burgers:
    1 // input
    Enter number of fries:
    1 // input
    Enter number of sodas:
    1 // input
```

Comment: You're almost there : Don't use python syntax for your for loop, you need an extra scope there. Which means adding { }. Also consider making auto n, const auto& n (it will avoid extra copying of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put braces around the whole body of the loop. It's not like Python, the indentation does not mark the loop body:

```
     for (auto n : products) {
        std::cout <<"Enter number of "<< n << ": " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> a;
        numbers.push_back(a);
     }
```

Comment: I would also suggest not making copies of the strings in `products`, so `for (auto& n : products)`

Comment: @ted so `const auto&` would suffice in this case, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, even better :)